# How to print the value entered in entry widget into canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I want to read an input from entry widget and display it in canvas on clicking the button.I created a canvas and I tried this code

```
entryval= Tkinter.Entry(framename)
entryval.pack()
button = Tkinter.Button(entryframe, text ="Enter",command=print)
button.pack()

def print()
   print entryval.get
```

But result is displaying only in terminal.not in canvas.

Please help.Thanks in advance

Comment: You can display the text entered with a call to a canvas' `create_text(x, y, text=entryval.get(), ...)` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick demo I made to help printing text to canvas:

```
from Tkinter import *
window = Tk()

def printVal():
    canvas = Canvas(window, width = 100, height = 100)
    canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
    string = entryval.get()
    canvas.create_text(50,50, text = string)

entryval = Entry(window)
entryval.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
button = Button(window, text = "Print", command = printVal)
button.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

window.mainloop()
```